# Sequelize-auto for SQLite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm trying to autogenerate my data models on sequelize for SQLite using squelize-auto on Windows. I have created my sqlite file with schema only, no data inside.
Also installed everything as indicated [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto).

The command I'm using looks like this:

```
sequelize-auto -h localhost -u dontcare -d "E:\full\path\to\my\database.db"  --dialect sqlite
```

Also tried with some other path styles like './database.db' etc.

And this is the answer I'm getting:

```
Executing (default): SELECT name FROM `sqlite_master` WHERE type='table' and name!='sqlite_sequence';
Done!
```

After this, the script creates a folder called "models" with nothing inside.

Does somebody know what's happening here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the problem:
-d should be the database name, not the path to the file.
For specify the file path, you should use the option -c indicating a JSON file. The storage attribute finally indicates that path.
The command should looks like this:

```
sequelize-auto -h localhost -u dontcare -d databasename  --dialect sqlite -c options.json
```

And options.json looks like this:

```
{
    "storage":"./database_file_name.db"
}
```

I hope this will be useful to someone.
Bye!

Comment: Hi @pepe ,  I am new to use sequelize-auto .So could you please help me to fix my error and my error is (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525480/how-to-declare-a-sequelize-auto-in-nodejs-program) please see this link , this is my error.So please guide me ..I am using windows 7 32bit and running my nodejs program on Enide 2015.

Comment: But what *is* the database name? The filename?

Comment: sequelize-auto uses sequelize, so you can use the sequelize examples for the various dialects

Comment: so what is the database name? has anyone figure this out?

Comment: @NiallFarrington for the sake of SQLite you don't need to specify host user and database values, as your database is just a file whose name has to be indicated in options.json. If you can't skip them on the command, use any value, say "dontcare".

Comment: @JoseNunez why you tell me this?

Comment: @NiallFarrington sorry, the message was for Maciej Jankowski. Cheers

Comment: @MaciejJankowski have a look on the previous comment "@NiallFarrington for the sake of SQLite you don't need to specify..."

Comment: `-d databasename` is `yourfilename.db`