# How to declare a sequelize-auto in nodejs program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When I am declaring a `sequelize-auto` in my program I'm getting an error like `o is not defined`.I tried so many ways to rectify this problem   but it doesn't work.I referred this link (https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto).

My Code  is

```
var Sequelizeauto = require('sequelize-auto');
var tableCreatin = new Sequelizeauto -o [modelPath] -d <loginform> -h <localhost> -u <root> -p <3306> -x <root> -e [mysql];
```

Error

```
ReferenceError: o is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodeProject\Sequeliser\server.js:23:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:118:18)
    at node.js:952:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run command `sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d sequelize_auto_test -h localhost -u my_username -p 5432 -x my_password -e postgres` in termintal, its not a JS code.

Comment: ,@Alexey B.First of all thanks and sorry to say .I execute that my above in my terminal .It showed `sequelize-auto is not recognized` .I am using windows 7.Could you please explain a bit more or give some sample code .It will more benefit for me .

Comment: I am running my program  on Enide 2015 @Alexey B

Comment: I dont know exactly what to do please help me @Alexey . i am sitting more than 3 hours ..with this problem please guide me

Comment: did you  run ``npm install sequelize-auto``? If yes try to exec command with full command path, for example ``./node_modules/sequelize-auto/bin/sequelize-auto PARAMS``. If it works its mean that you not specify right PATH environment variable

Comment: I tried it showed like this `D:\NodeProject\Sequeliser\node_modules\sequelize-auto\bin>sequelize-auto -o "./modal" -d loginform -h localhost -u root -p 3306 -x root -e mysql` got an error
`'sequelize-auto' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: hi @Alexey Now I understand the probs where I was  stuck . I found the answer with your guidelines . Thanks !

Comment: oops ! I got a success message in cmd tool . But it does create the table in  side DB. Below I posted my result .Could you please help me ..
`C:\Users\suresh\AppData\Roaming\npm>sequelize-auto -o "./modal" -d sequelizeauto
 -h localhost -u root -p 3306 -x root -e mysql`
I got a message like this `Executing (default): SHOW TABLES;
Done!` but the table which i have in my cde is not created .. please help

Answer (score 3):

I am using grunt to run this command. I was getting the same error when I was running grunt schema command. It got resolved by installing sequelize-auto globally: `npm install -g sequelize-auto`

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable PowerShell scripts execution .

For details see:

https://windowsloop.com/enable-powershell-scripts-execution-windows-10/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29970847)

Comment: How does one "enable powershell scripts execution"? (without going to the link)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone arriving here after all these years - this actually (at least now) can be done, and in a very straightforward way. as can be found in their [sample](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/blob/master/sample/export.js)

```
const SequelizeAuto = require('sequelize-auto');

const output = "./models";
const options = { directory: output, caseFile: 'l', caseModel: 'p', caseProp: 'c', lang: 'js', useDefine: false, singularize: true, spaces: true, indentation: 2 };

const config = {
    dialect: '...',
    host: "...",
    port: ...,
    dbname: "...",
    user: "...",
    pass: "...",
    ...options
};

var auto = new SequelizeAuto(config.dbname, config.user, config.pass, config);

auto.run().then(data => {
  const tableNames = Object.keys(data.tables);
  console.log(tableNames);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must install sequelize-auto and mysql2 globally then run command (sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d sequelize_auto_test -h localhost -u my_username -p 5432 -x my_password -e postgres)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).